# New SSL certificate is 2 years old

Tags: apache, ssl, sha

I have installed a new certificate on an existing webserver.
Ran "https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html". says the certificate
is 700+ days old.

The domain is "www.infocon-inc.com"
Certificate is SHA2.
Created a free certificated made sure sha256.
  using both the configure file and the command line -sha256.
running Apache 2.2+ with openssl 1+
Checked IP Address
checked the firewall https is open port.
restart Apache, everytime I updated the certificate.
Still get "ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" error in the browser.
Site has been up for years.

Any ideas as to where to look for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was there was in ssl.conf referenced localhost.crt and localhost.key.